# Typescript - classes composed of classes (nested classes?)

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen some post's about modules and namespaces but I haven't found anything online about doing something like this (not sure if it should be an interface or a class and I'm not convinced it matters). I'm using them to bind to some JSON data that is returned.

topLevelJsonElement.ts:

```
export interface TopLevelJsonElement {
    item: string;
    item2: SubItems[];
}
```

subItems.ts

```
export interface SubItems {
    item: number;
    item2: any;
}
```

Perhaps I could compose or nest them down as many levels as I wanted? But do you see how `TopLevelJsonElement` CONTAINS as list of `SubItems`

Currently I'm getting an error:
`topLevelJsonElement"' has no exported member 'TopLevelJsonElement '.`

Comment: If you are using the cli, restart your dev server. I've run into issues where the bundling process fails to pick up exported interfaces if they are by themselves in the file. Restarting the dev server seems to fix it

Comment: When transpiled to regular JS, exported TS "interfaces" apparently disappear, so they're mainly handy as a guide while coding. Couldn't make nested classes work either - I don't think that's supported. If you need to instantiate an object of a particular type at runtime, or use one in another file/object, use a Class.

Comment: They are interfaces, not classes. The question contains no information on how they are used.

Comment: @estus I'm using them to bind to some JSON data that is returned in an http.get. I've updated the question. Sorry I didn't think it mattered. I'm more concerned with if in general what I'm attempting to do is feasible in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LLai in the comments. I'm using angular-cli and I had to restart my local host (ng serve).

Also I was able to boil my interface down to a similar version so I didn't need two interfaces. Not sure if it would have worked with the two. Something I need to try when I have more time.

```
export interface JsonElement {
    item: string;
    item2: JsonElement [];
}
```